# function that browses every folder in a folder

Tags: python, python-os

i give a path to a function and i want this funtion to watch in every folder in this path and if there is a folder inside of a folder : watch in too.

```
def function(path):
   for element in os.listdir(path):
       element_path = os.path.abspath(element)
       if os.isdir(element_path):
           path = os.path.join(path, element)
           function(path)
        elif ... # elif elment is an img do something
```

This code works but when there is a folder in a folder it doesn't work :/

Comment: `element_path = os.path.join(path,element)`

Comment: Why not use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre dans le chemin que je lui précise : il y a deux dossiers mais il n'ouvre pas les deux

Comment: @Galen I don't understand how does it work very well

Comment: `os.isdir(element_path)` 1) doesn't exist and 2) is false because it doesn't exist. The join is made too late.